# Can you specify both hex & scientific to from_chars?

Tags: c++, c++17

from_chars will be a new feature in C++17. It isn't clear to me whether you can specify `chars_format::hex` and `chars_format::scientific` at the same time.

If yes, how do you mark the exponent part? 'e' cannot be used because it could be mistaken for the hexadecimal value of fourteen during parsing.

Comment: If you read e.g. [this floating point literal reference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/floating_literal) you will see that `e` isn't used to denote exponents for floating point hexadecimal values, but a `p`.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I'm currently working on a crude temporal implementation of to_chars and from_chars, because I need their functionality for another project.